# Some styles are not reflecting when using createstyles from material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I am doing styling like below,

```
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
    createStyles({
      label:{
     
      },
      mandatory: {
        "&::after":{
        content: " *",
        color: "red",
        }
    },
    box:{
      width: "90px",
      height: "10px",
      margin: "5px auto",
      backgroundColor: "white",
      "&::-webkit-scrollbar":{
        width:"3px",
    }
    },
    })
  );
  const classes = useStyles();
<label className={[classes.mandatory,classes.label].join(" ")}>
```

***But Mandatory icon is not appeared and the same way scrollbar style also not changed*** If I use seperate css class, both styles are working fine. But I need to do only by using createstyles. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: we will undertstand more if you provide codesandbox.io

Comment: adding a style with `createStyles` doesn't mean it'll apply right away. Because these styles need to be manually consumed by that component. This is very different to `css` even though it looks like a css. My comments applies to the new `key` especially.